# Problem with JS (React). Button doesn't work

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, react-native, user-interface

I created Backend part and after that, I started work with UI.I used JS (React). It is my first experience and I get a problem. When user click on a submit button I get this error:
[image]

I absolutely sure that problem in UI part. I think that I did something wrong. My backend part works good. And Problem not in a CORS. But I don't see what I do wrong in JS(React). Could you tell me about my issues?
Js Files:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { notification, Alert, Spin, Form, Input, Button, Typography } from 'antd';
import { usePromise } from 'innroad.common.ui';
import * as apiService from 'services/ApiService';
import { LAYOUT, TAIL_LAYOUT } from 'constants/layouts';
import styles from './AddTownCreation.scss';

const AddTownCreation = () => {
  const onFail = () => notification.error({ message: 'some error occured while creating template' });

  const [{ data, isLoading }, createNewTown] = usePromise(apiService.createTown, { initialData: [], onFail });

  const handleFormFinish = (formValue) => createNewTown(formValue);

  return (
    <>
      <Spin spinning={isLoading}>
        <Typography.Title>Create New Town</Typography.Title>
        {data.length > 0 && (<Alert message={`New town id : ${data.join(',')}`} type="info" />)}
        <Form {...LAYOUT} onFinish={handleFormFinish}>
          <Form.Item
            name="name"
            label="Town Name :"
            rules={[{ whitespace: true, required: true, message: 'This is required field' }]}
          >
            <Input />
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item {...TAIL_LAYOUT}>
            <Button htmlType="submit" className={styles.rightMargin}>Submit</Button>
            <Button type="link" className="ant-btn"><Link to="/">Cancel</Link></Button>
          </Form.Item>
        </Form>
      </Spin>
    </>
  );
};

export default AddTownCreation;
```

AddTownCreation.scss JS:

```
.rightMargin {
    margin-right: 8px;
}
```

Index.JS:

```
export { default } from './AddTownCreation';
```

Api Service. JS:

```
import { get, post } from './HttpService';

/**
 * ---------------------------------
 * endpoints
 * ---------------------------------
 */

export const createTown = async (data) => post('/add.town', data);
```

**Backend part**
API

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using innSupportTools.Services;
using innSupportTools.ViewModels;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace XXX
{
    [Route("api")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TownController : ControllerBase
    {
        public readonly ITownService _townService;

        public TownController(ITownService townService)
        {
            _townService = townService;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("add.town")]
        public async Task<int> InsertTown([FromBody] TownViewModel town)
        {
            return await _townService.InsertTown(town.Name);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("GetTown/{townId}")]
        public async Task<TownViewModel> GetTown(int townId)
        {
            return await _townService.GetTown(townId);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Its a `cors` issue not a frontend issue. Allow origin url from backend

Answer (score 0):

There is two issues

1.you have to fix the cors issue in backend

2.`export { default } from './AddTownCreation';**` this is wrong import statement in index.js file, this should be `import AddTownCreation from './AddTownCreation';`

Comment: I guess OP is exporting function in index.js, could be at any location, which seems to be correct. OP doesn't have any issue with import/export too.

Answer (score 0):

CORS is a famous problem. The error stems from a security mechanism that browsers implement called the same-origin policy its for "cross-site request forgery". you can check on youtube you have many tutorials on it.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just your local home project to get to know React you can just set up your UI application on the same web server and no issue will happen